# Drawing PWM figure using C programming

Tags: c

A friend of mine tries to draw a PWM figure with C language, I've written these codes just a couple of minutes ago, but it seems that the function doesn't fill the last blanks till the period of the function. When I typed, period - signal, it doesn't fill the remaining blanks. Maybe I made a mistake counting the number of dashes. 
[image]

```
/*This program draws the fullness of a given pulse width modulation parameters, period and fullness*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  int period,fullness; // we declare the period and fullness variables
  int  signal;          // we declare the signal variable 
  int i,j,k,l,m;          // iteration variables

  printf("Enter the period: "); // prompting the user to type the period
  scanf("%d", &period);       // reading the period
  printf("Enter the fullness of the signal: ");
  scanf("%d", &fullness);                       // prompting and reading the fullness
  signal = (period * fullness) / 100;  // we calculate the signal 
  printf("1");                        // we start drawing the PWM figure
  printf("|");

  for(k=1; k <= signal ; k++)            // we put dashes until it reaches to the signal
  {
      printf("---");
  }

  printf("\n");                    // we jump to the next line
  for (i=1;i<=10;i++)
  {                         // drawing for the figure again until it reaches to 11
      printf(" |\n");
  }
  printf("0");
  printf("|");                       // after the eleventh one 

  for(l=1; l <= signal; l++)        // we calculate for the blank spaces
  {
      printf("   "); 
  }

  for(m=1; m <= (period - signal); m++)           // we fill the last part 
  {
    printf("---");
  }

  printf("\n");  // we jump to the other line
  printf("  ");

  for(j=1; j <= period; j++)       // printing the numbers bottom of the screen
  {

    printf("%d  ",j);

  }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Step through your code with a debugger.

Comment: i miss something but where?

Comment: After the 10's we need to add another dash for the 2 digit numbers.. that's all!!! case closed.